# How auto generate Database in SQLite from Entity Framework?

Tags: .net, asp.net, entity-framework, sqlite, integration-testing

I using SQLite to do integration tests in my app, i want to every test recreate the database automatically.

That's my connectionStrings:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DbConnection"
      providerName="System.Data.SQLite"
      connectionString="Data Source=D:\Questiona2011_MVC\Trunk\Questiona2011.Tests\Questiona2011" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

That's my DatabaseInitializer:

```
public class DatabaseInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<Questiona2011Context>
{
}
```

And in my global.asax Application_start:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DatabaseInitializer());
```

**And I'm getting this error:** *Model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata. Ensure that IncludeMetadataConvention has been added to the DbModelBuilder conventions.*

Comment: I'm not sure if SQLite provides ability to create and delete database. It didn't few months ago.